# Lua errors in starwarsrp server

Tags: lua

[ERROR] addons/darkrpmodification/lua/darkrp_customthings/jobs.lua:34: '}' expected (to close '{' at line 21) near 'category'
  1. unknown - addons/darkrpmodification/lua/darkrp_customthings/jobs.lua:0

I am currently coding a server on a fairly well know game called gmod
I had the server as DarkRP but recently decided to change it to starwarsrp because every day DarkRP becomes more and more chaotic.

This is the error im getting with the code
Im unsure what the problem is as im fairly new with lua and if you know the solution to the problem i would very much appreciate it

```
    --[[---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    DarkRP custom jobs
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

    This file contains your custom jobs.
    This file should also contain jobs from DarkRP that you edited.

    Note: If you want to edit a default DarkRP job, first disable it in     darkrp_config/disabled_defaults.lua
        Once you've done that, copy and paste the job to this file and edit it.

    The default jobs can be found here:
    https://github.com/FPtje/DarkRP/blob/master/gamemode/config/jobrelated.lua

    For examples and explanation please visit this wiki page:
    http://wiki.darkrp.com/index.php/DarkRP:CustomJobFields


    Add jobs under the following line:
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------]]

    TEAM_CT = DarkRP.createJob("Clone Trooper", { -- Name
        color = Color(255, 255, 255, 255), -- Team color
        model = "models/player/mossman.mdl", -- Player model
        description = [[Your a single clone
                            You have no importance]],  -- Job description
        weapons = {"weapon_empty_hands"}, -- Additional weapons
        command = "CT", -- Command to become the job
        max = 100, -- Maximum amount of said job
        salary = 0, -- Salary
        admin = 0, -- Requires Admin? 1 for yes, 0 for no.
        vote = false, -- Do they need to vote? true for yes, false for no.
        hasLicense = false, -- Has a license
        customCheck = function(ply) return ply:GetNWString("usergroup") ==     "clonetrooper" end -- The extra check function. Enter nil or nothing to not have     an extra check
        category = "Clone",


    })







    --[[---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Define which team joining players spawn into and what team you change to if     demoted
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------]]
    GAMEMODE.DefaultTeam = TEAM_CITIZEN


--[[---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Define which teams belong to civil protection
Civil protection can set warrants, make people wanted and do some other police related things
---------------------------------------------------------------------------]]
GAMEMODE.CivilProtection = {
    [TEAM_POLICE] = true,
    [TEAM_CHIEF] = true,
    [TEAM_MAYOR] = true,
}

--[[---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Jobs that are hitmen (enables the hitman menu)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------]]
DarkRP.addHitmanTeam(TEAM_MOB)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a comma after `end` in:

```
    customCheck = function(ply) return ply:GetNWString("usergroup") ==     "clonetrooper" end -- The extra check function. Enter nil or nothing to not have     an extra check
```